# ¿Como hacer que adentro de un v-bind::id concatene el index del v-for y le sume 1?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

**veran tengo u v-for lo que quiero hacer es un collapse con bootstrap-vue**
pero  el id sea dinamico comenzando en 1 no en 0

```
<div role="tablist">
                    <div v-for="(log, index) in logrosExtras" >
                        <b-card bg-variant="dark" text-variant="white" no-body class="mb-1" >
                            <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
                                <b-btn block href="#" v-b-toggle.accordion1 variant="dark">{{log.name}} {{++index}}</b-btn>
                            </b-card-header>
                            <b-collapse :id="'accordion'+index++" visible accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
                                <b-card-body>
                                    <div>
                                        <table class="table table-dark" >
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>1</td>
                                                    <td>2</td>
                                                    <td>3</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </b-card-body>
                            </b-collapse>
                        </b-card>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

en esta linea esta el problema

```
                                <b-collapse :id="'accordion'+index++" visible accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
```

Comment: ¿Que error te muestra?

Comment: que no se puede renderirzar